# Composite Tasks using OptaPlanner

Tags: optaplanner

I am trying to build Pools of Workers in a chained TWVRP scenario with multiple anchors. One Composite Task will be split into multiple smaller Task and distributed onto the chains in an optimal manner. Now, how can I ensure that all tasks that belong to the same composite task have the same start time? Can I solve this using custom moves or is using Drools to model this behaviour my only option?

I studied the documentation on custom moves but I just couldn't figure out how to use them in this case... Does anyone have a hint for me?

Answer (score 1):

Make the startTime of a single Task a **shadow variable** that is the maximum previousTaskEndTime of all the single tasks that belong to the same CompositeTask.

Comment: Dear Mr. De Smet, thank you for your help. However, it seems that I forgot to mention that the scenario is time windowed, but all the Tasks in one group have the same earliest start and latest start, of course. So should I have an additional start time shadow variable that updates whenever the arrival time of one of the task changes? and how do I make sure that all the other tasks will be shifted on their chains accordingly? If exactly the same arrival time for all tasks is required and the solver performs a swap for only one

Comment: of the composite tasks, the position will never change after the construction, right? Kind regards